# images not showing after transfer

Tags: images, urls, encoding

After transfer Wordpress to another host some images not shown on pages.

I fixed all permissions firstly but I realized that images which contains characters like ç,ş not recognised by server.

In my previous server there is no problem about that.

For example;

www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/KÜLLÜK-768x791.jpg

its could be reachable on previous server. But now, its returning with 404 error and Im sure about there is no missing file.

how can I solve this problem?